# how to view video in activity that is chosen from the gallery

Tags: android, video

I am implementing video uploading functionality in an android application.I can choose a video from gallery but I can not view it in my activity.I dont know how to put a video from gallery to videoview of an activity
My code to select video from gallery is :

```
mChoose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            intent.setType("video/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_ID);
        }
    });
```

onActivityResult Method code

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
    InputStream stream = null;
    if(requestCode == REQUEST_ID && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
    {
        try
        {
            stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
            //System.out.println(data.getData());
            mVideo.setVideoPath(path);
            path = getRealPathFromURI(getApplicationContext(), data.getData());
            //getRealPathFromURI is method in class to obtain path from uri
            System.out.println(path);

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(stream != null)
        {
            try
            {
                stream.close();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this Code

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mVideo = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        intent.setType("video/*");
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
    }
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        if(requestCode == 1 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
        {
            try
            {
                String path = data.getData().toString();
                mVideo.setVideoPath(path);
                mVideo.requestFocus();
                mVideo.start();

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you it really working,I am now able to play video in activity.But can I just show an Image of selected video and if user want to play then he/she can play it by pressing video button.Video should not play automatically

Comment: You have to create a thumbnail from the video path and you can apply it as  mVideo.setBackgroundDrawable(bitmapDrawable); to it or create another view overlapping to it. If my answer helped you please accept my answer.

Comment: if you do not want to start it automatically just remove mVideo.start() and you can add mVideo.setMediaController(new MediaController(MainActivity.this)); to get play pause controls

Answer (score 0):

```
VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoview);
Uri vidFile = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getAbsolutePath() + "path of the video");

    videoView.setVideoURI(vidFile);
    videoView
            .setMediaController(new MediaController(PlayVideoActivity.this));
    videoView.setVisibility(1);
    videoView.bringToFront();
    videoView.requestFocus();
```